# P&S QFT derivation of (9.72) (correlation function of spinor)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, path-integral, dirac-delta-distributions, correlation-functions

On P&S QFT book page 302, the book considered spinor two point correlation function derivation, begin with
\begin{equation}
\left\langle 0\left|T \psi\left(x_1\right) \bar{\psi}\left(x_2\right)\right| 0\right\rangle=\frac{\int \mathcal{D} \bar{\psi} \mathcal{D} \psi \exp \left[i \int d^4 x \bar{\psi}(i \not \partial-m) \psi\right] \psi\left(x_1\right) \bar{\psi}\left(x_2\right)}{\int \mathcal{D} \bar{\psi} \mathcal{D} \psi \exp \left[i \int d^4 x \bar{\psi}(i \not \partial-m) \psi\right]} \tag{A}
\end{equation}
then
$$\left\langle 0\left|T \psi\left(x_1\right) \bar{\psi}\left(x_2\right)\right| 0\right\rangle=\frac{\text{det}[-i(i\not\partial-m)][-i(i\not\partial-m)]^{-1}_{x_1,x_2}}{\text{det}[-i(i\not\partial-m)]}=[-i(i\not\partial-m)]^{-1}_{x_1,x_2} \tag{B}$$
define Green's Function:
$$(i\not\partial-m)S_F(x-y)=i\delta^4 (x-y) \tag{C}$$
multiply each side with $(i\not\partial-m)^{-1}$, then
$$S_F(x-y)=-\delta^4 (x-y)[-i(i\not\partial-m)]^{-1} \tag{D}$$
while from (9.72),
$$\left\langle 0\left|T \psi\left(x_1\right) \bar{\psi}\left(x_2\right)\right| 0\right\rangle=S_F\left(x_1-x_2\right)=\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{i e^{-i k \cdot\left(x_1-x_2\right)}}{\not k-m+i \epsilon} \tag{9.72}$$

So I am confused:

(1) It seems there is an additional $-\delta^4(x-y)$ in D?

(2) How does the indices $x_1$ and $x_2$ contracted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can't just "multiply both sides" by the Green's function. You have to proceed in another manner, like so:

1. Take the Fourier transform of $(C)$:
   \begin{equation}
   (i\not\partial-m)S_F=i\delta \Longrightarrow (\not p-m)\tilde{S}_F=i
   \end{equation}
2. Multiply both sides by $(\not p-m)^{-1}$ and take the inverse Fourier transform:
   \begin{equation}
   \tilde{S}_F = \frac{i}{\not p-m} \Longrightarrow S_F(x-y)=\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{ie^{-i p(x-y)}}{\not p-m}
   \end{equation}
   And voilà.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's make sense! But it seems that there is a minus sign difference! Would the $[-i(i\not\partial-m)]^{-1}$ in $k-$space  equal to $\frac{i}{\not p-m}$?

Comment: It is possible that I've made a sign error, however, I don't see where right now. All I can say is that $[-i(i\not \partial-m)]^{-1}=i (i \not \partial -m)^{-1}$, hence I don't see where is my mistake...

Comment: Oh, I see, you are right, thank you very much! I am really appreciate your help!

Comment: May I add another comment to help my understanding? Could I think $(i\not\partial_x-m)[i(i\not\partial-m)_{x,y}^{-1}]=i\delta(x-y)$, so we regard $[i(i\not\partial-m)_{x,y}^{-1}]$ as the Green function of operator $(i\not\partial_x-m)$?

Comment: @Daren Yes this absolutely the purpose of the manipulation I've done. But you have to be careful to not confuse Green's function and Feynman's propagator, there are a few differences as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Position_space)

Comment: I see, thank you very much, thanks for your help again!

Comment: Hello, I find that I still don't totally understand it, could you please take a look of my this new post ?https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/737686/spinor-field-path-quantization?

Comment: Jeanbaptiste, can I interest you in making this mathematics understandable to me? https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/692833